# VueJS Calendar go back and forth one month

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have build a calendar that shows a table of dates and the corresponding day, and i want to add the function to change between months. The Method i have made here does "work". It goes back a month when i click a button that takes this function. but only once, and this is because the selectedDate does not update, so when i try to debug using the console.log(selectedDate) that i commented out it still prints todays date..   Hope someone can help me out here

```
methods: {
  prevMonth() {
    var selectedDate = moment(new Date());
    let futureMonth = moment(selectedDate.subtract(1, 'month')).startOf('month')
        selectedDate = futureMonth;
    //return console.log(selectedDate)
    this.days = [...Array(futureMonth.daysInMonth())].map((_, i) => {
      return {
        date: futureMonth.clone().add(i, "day"),
        workhours: Math.floor(Math.random()*10),
        overtime: Math.floor(Math.random()*10),
        flextime: 0,
        sickness: 0,
        vacation: 0,
      }

    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the selectedDate to `moment(new Date())` every time you run this method. So it always goes back one month based on today.

You need to keep the state of selectedDate, something like this should work:

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedDate: undefined
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.selectedDate = moment(new Date())
},
methods: {
  prevMonth() {
    let futureMonth = moment(this.selectedDate.subtract(1, 'month')).startOf('month')
    this.selectedDate = futureMonth;
    ......
    })
  }
}
```